# how to build kate with cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, kate

Dear stackoverflow users,

I'm trying to compile kate from source but I'm getting an error with a not declared variable.
So far these are the commands I'm using:

```
#! /bin/bash
cmake \  
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \  
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/kde/usr \  
-D KDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS:BOOL=ON \  
-D TARGET_include_directories:PATH="/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/" \  
-D Qt5_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH="/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/" \  
-D Qt5_LIBRARY_DIRS:PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/" \  
../kate/  
make  
make install
```

Please find below the error during compiling: I think it has to be related with not including some path file that should be there which declares the variable QWidgetAction, however I'm not sure why, since I installed all required packages as per the website.

(qtbase5-dev qtscript5-dev extra-cmake-modules plasma-framework-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5config-dev libkf5activities-dev kinit-dev kdoctools-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5parts-dev libkf5guiaddons-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5jobwidgets-dev kio-dev libkf5texteditor-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev libgit2-dev).
The reason I'm compiling it is because I messed up with my original installed kate and I just can't load back all plugins, since my /.config kate folder is gone. Please any help is appreciated.

> [ 69%] Automatic moc for target katecloseexceptplugin    [ 69%] Built
>   target katecloseexceptplugin_automoc     [ 71%] Built target
>   katecloseexceptplugin     [ 71%] Automatic moc for target
>   katesqlplugin      [ 71%] Built target katesqlplugin_automoc     [
>   71%] Building CXX object addons/katesql/CMakeFiles/katesqlplugin.dir
>   /katesqlview.cpp.o
>   /home/pablo/kde/kate/addons/katesql/katesqlview.cpp: In member
>   function ‘void     KateSQLView::setupActions()’:
>   /home/pablo/kde/kate/addons/katesql/katesqlview.cpp:141:3: error:
>   ‘QWidgetAction’ was not declared in this scope        QWidgetAction
>   *wa = new QWidgetAction(this);        ^      /home/pablo/kde/kate/addons/katesql/katesqlview.cpp:141:18: error:
>   ‘wa’ was     not declared in this scope         QWidgetAction *wa =
>   new QWidgetAction(this);
>                     ^     /home/pablo/kde/kate/addons/katesql/katesqlview.cpp:141:27: error:
>   expected      type-specifier before ‘QWidgetAction’
>   QWidgetAction *wa = new QWidgetAction(this);
>
>                              ^      addons/katesql/CMakeFiles/katesqlplugin.dir/build.make:96: recipe for
>   target
>
>   'addons/katesql/CMakeFiles/katesqlplugin.dir/katesqlview.cpp.o' failed
>   make[2]:* 
>   [addons/katesql/CMakeFiles/katesqlplugin.dir/katesqlview.cpp.o]
>   Error 1      CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2439: recipe for target
>   'addons/katesql/CMakeFiles    /katesqlplugin.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: * [addons/katesql/CMakeFiles/katesqlplugin.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed      make: *** [all]
>   Error 2

Answer (score 0):

QWidgetAction is a part of Qt. Have you got the Qt libraries and headers properly in your path?

Header: #include

Comment: Qt was installed using apt-get install qtbase5-dev. And it looks that the cmake is recognizing it-s path. It is just specifically this QWidget which id doesn't seem to find. Do you know how to verify within the cmake if the path is properly defined? Thanks